# Selenium Grid: 2 nodes in the same pc

Tags: c#, selenium-grid

I have an issue with Selenium Remote Server as Grid. I am testing the application y 1 computer, and I start up the server and 4 nodes, one for FireFox, one for Chrome, other for Internet Explorer and the last one for HtmlUnit.

When I select FireFox or HtmlUnit there is no problem. But with Chrome and IE it depends on which one we started first. The node that we started first is the one that function.

I have the application in C# with selenium RemoteWebDriver.  The code is:

```
if (browserId == 1)
  webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.HubUri),
                                          DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
else if (browserId == 2)
  webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.HubUri), 
                                          DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
else if (browserId == 3)
  webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.HubUri), 
                                  DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
else if (browserId == 4)
  webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.HubUri), 
                                  DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

I started the Server with the following line of command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -role hub
```

The Nodes:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\Utilities\Grid\IEdriverServer.exe" -role node -hub http://"localhost":4444/grid/register -port 5559
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -role node -hub http://"localhost":4444/grid/register -port 5557
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Utilities\Grid\chromedriver.exe" -role node -hub http://"localhost":4444/grid/register -port 30000
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -role node -hub http://"localhost":4444/grid/register -browser browserName=htmlunit -port 5558
```

I want to know if all is correct and if is possible to run those nodes in a same PC.

I am using Firefox, Intermet Explorer, Chrome and HtmlUnit.  The conflict is with Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
BrowsersConfiguration:

port:5559
servlets:[]
host:localhost
cleanUpCycle:5000
browserTimeout:0
hubHost:localhost
Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Utilities\Grid\IEdriverServer.exe:
registerCycle:5000
hub:http://localhost:4444/grid/register
capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout:-1
url:http://"localhost":5559
remoteHost:http://"localhost":5559
prioritizer:null
register:true
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true
nodePolling:5000
proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
maxSession:5
role:node
hubPort:4444
timeout:300000

DefaultRemoteProxy (version : 2.38.0)
id : http://"localhost":5557, OS : VISTA
BrowsersConfiguration
port:5557
servlets:[]
host:"localhost"
cleanUpCycle:5000
browserTimeout:0
hubHost:localhost
registerCycle:5000
hub:http://localhost:4444/grid/register
capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout:-1
url:http://"localhost":5557
remoteHost:http://"localhost":5557
prioritizer:null
register:true
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true
nodePolling:5000
proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
maxSession:5
role:node
hubPort:4444
timeout:300000

DefaultRemoteProxy (version : 2.38.0)
id : http://"localhost":30000, OS : VISTA
BrowsersConfiguration
port:30000
servlets:[]
host:"localhost"
cleanUpCycle:5000
browserTimeout:0
hubHost:localhost
registerCycle:5000
hub:http://localhost:4444/grid/register
capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout:-1
url:http://"localhost":30000
remoteHost:http://"localhost":30000
prioritizer:null
register:true
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true
nodePolling:5000
proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
maxSession:5
role:node
Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Utilities\Grid\chromedriver.exe:
hubPort:4444
timeout:300000

DefaultRemoteProxy (version : 2.38.0)
id : http://"localhost":5558, OS : VISTA
BrowsersConfiguration
port:5558
servlets:[]
host: "localhost"
cleanUpCycle:5000
browserTimeout:0
hubHost:localhost
registerCycle:5000
hub:http://localhost:4444/grid/register
capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout:-1
url:http://"localhost":5558
remoteHost:http://"localhost":5558
prioritizer:null
register:true
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true
nodePolling:5000
proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
browser:browserName=htmlunit
maxSession:5
role:node
hubPort:4444
timeout:300000
```

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  The Grid only works with version 12.0.712.0 or later.

Comment: You are not specifying the browserName for the first 3 nodes. How does your grid console look like? Can you put a screenshot of grid console here?

Comment: Thanks you for your quickly answer. Brian, I have a chromedriver version 2.8 and the Google Chrome browser version is 31.0.1650.63 m

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need to run 4 different nodes on the same PC.  If you run one Grid Node on that PC, it will support running all the instances that you require.   One Grid node can execute multiple browsers of multiple types.   Was there some reason why you thought otherwise?  Only only reason I can think of otherwise is if your trying to run those separate browsers in different Linux xvfb sessions?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But If I have only one how I control the drivers?  For example the IE and Chrome need a driver to run. That's why I use 4 Nodes.  Can you tell me how to configure the Grid Node to run all the browsers with any problem?

Comment: Yes, I have created .bat files that set all that up for you in the root directory of this Git repo:  https://github.com/djangofan/selenium-gradle-example   .  Running them requires you install "WGet for windows".  I also made .sh  bash examples also for Linux.